# Is there a way to make a character variable resolve before passing it as an argument?

Tags: sas

```
data myout ;
set braw.accounts end = eof;
     fname = "BANK_ACCT"; 
        retain countmissing cm2 0;
        if missing(fname) = 0 then countmissing = countmissing+1; 
        if missing(BANK_ACCT) = 0 then cm2 = cm2 +1; 

    if eof then output; 
    keep fname countmissing cm2;

run;
```

(^ don't know why that isn't indenting).

So what I'm wanting to do, is read in the names of variables from the dictionary, and then perform analysis on each of those variables, counting the number missing.

The problem is that when I pass fname into missing() it's looking for a variable called 'fname' not 'BANK_ACCT'. how can tell it to resolve before passing it in?

Comment: I think you'd be better off using the NMISS statistical specification in PROC MEANS or PROC SUMMARY to find this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this:

1)  Construct a macro variable that contains your variable names, then define an array.  The previous question you posted would be a good place to start.  Something like this:

```
proc sql;
 select name into :varlist separated by ' ' from dictionary.columns 
 where memname='DATASET' and libname='LIBRARY'
 and <conditions defining which columns you want>;
quit;

data myout ;
set braw.accounts end = eof;
    array fname &varlist;
    do _t = 1 to dim(fname); 
        if missing(fname[_t]) = 0 then countmissing+1; 
        if missing(BANK_ACCT) = 0 then cm2 +1; 
    end;
    if eof then output; 
    keep fname countmissing cm2;  
run;
```

(Also introduced a new concept - +1; automatically does the retain var 0; bit)

You might find it useful, by the way, to use CALL SYMPUT to put countmissing to a macro variable rather than outputting a row (depending on what you're using it for).

2)  Similar to 1, but you can create an array of all variables, or all numeric variables, or all variables from one point to another point.

```
array fname _all_; *will only work if all variables are same type;
array fname _numeric_;
array fname var_first -- var_last; *all variables in order from left to right from var_first to var_last;
```

3)  Operate on a 'normalized' dataset, so a dataset with only two variables (or a few) - 'varname' and 'value'.  This requires some (significant) work to create, so only useful in certain circumstances.

4) Use some method other than a dataset to figure this out.  For exmaple, PROC FREQ or PROC TABULATE can trivially give you the number of missing values of each variable (using the missing option).